# SQL How to compare DateTime to minutes

Tags: sql

I have two different set of DateTime in database.
How do i select time to minutes. I want to select User if his InTime and OutTime is same up to minutes and NOT seconds. So in this case it should select User1 and User2. . The seconds are ignored. How to create such SQL query?

```
Table: DailyTimeAttendance

User: 1
InTime: 2018-01-01 05:01:07
OutTime: 2018-01-01 05:01:05

User: 2
InTime: 2018-01-01 02:02:04
OutTime: 2018-01-01 02:02:09

User: 3
InTime: 2018-01-01 09:04:05
OutTime: 2018-01-01 09:06:10

Expected Output SQL: 
User1 InTime 2018-01-01 00:01 compared to OutTime 2018-01-01 00:01 is TRUE
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (You've got some product specific answers. Don't waste people's time writing answers for "wrong" dbms.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use DATEDIFF functions if you are using the Microsoft SQL Server, This function returns the count (as a signed integer value) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.  EXAMPLE (if are in same minute)

```
SELECT * FROM DailyTimeAttendance 
WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE,InTime,OutTime)=0
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql:

```
select User, Intime, OutTime, 
case when date_format(Intime, '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i') = date_format(OutTime, '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i')
then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end
from DailyTimeAttendance
```

Answer (score 0):

This should serve your purpose.

```
select * from 
DailyTimeAttendance where
 CONVERT(DATE_FORMAT(InTime,'%Y-%m-%d-%H:%i:00'), DATETIME) = 
 CONVERT(DATE_FORMAT(OutTime,'%Y-%m-%d-%H:%i:00'), DATETIME)
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.